Why the request in one session goes to the same pod in the Kubernetes cluster
I have an HTTP rest based java application, All my request from one session (one browser tab) always goes to the same pod (say pod 1). When I open the same application in incognito, the request goes to the another pod (say pod 2) and further request from the same browser goes to the same pod (say pod 2) again. so the load is not distributed for each request.
I used the Classic Load Balancer in the AWS and it points to the 3 targets of EC2 instance where the Kubernetes cluster has the pods deployed.
I could confirm that the CLB is not configured with Sticky Sessions and with my limited knowledge on the Kubernetes cluster, I verified the 'routes' configuration (annotations) in my namespace and not able to find any of the configuration related to sticky sessions,
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    haproxy.router.openshift.io/timeout: 300s
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: appname-routing
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: mynamespace

Also routing policy in Route53 is 'simple',
Still I am not sure why my request from one session always goes to the same pod. When I open the same application in incognito, the request goes to the another pod and further request from the same browser goes to the same pod again.
Anyone faced this issue, how did you resolve this? Any specific  configuration I need to check on?

Can you tell if HTTP persistent connections are in use?  If the browser maintains a single TCP channel to the server, there will never be a point for a load balancer to redistribute the traffic over that single connection.

@DavidMaze Okay possibly Http persistent connection could have cause this. One question in this - From the networking perspective, How does the TCP Connection works from Brower -> Load Balancer -> Kubernetes -> Pod -> webserver.
